# How do I target the innerHTML of a <span> element that does not have any ID or tag in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have HTML on my WordPress site that looks like this:

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix">
  <header class="page-header">
    <h1 class="page-title">
      <span>
        Archives
      </span>
    </h1>
  </header><!-- .page-header -->

  <div class="article-container">
```

How do I replace the string "Archives" with "test string"?

This is what I have so far, but does not work.

```
<?php
?>

<script>
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

for (var i=0; i < spans.length; i++)
{
    if (spans[i].innerHTML.contains("Archives"))
    {
        //is this the "Welcome" span?
        spans[i].innerHTML = "test string";  //change to new value
        break;                               //hop out of the loop, we're done
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try to put your JS code into a document ready function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this

```
<script>
function changeme(){
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for(var i=0;i<spans.length; i++) {
    if(spans[i].innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase()==="archives") {       //is this the "Welcome" span?
    spans[i].innerHTML = "test string";  //change to new value
    break;                                  //hop out of the loop, we're done
    }
}
}
window.onload = function() {
changeme();
 };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick! is it because of the empty space?

Comment: Yeah, always try to trim out empty spaces outside of strings so you can make your check more clear, and use case-insensitive search as well, also there may be the case that your html may have whitespaces more often and you were not be able to filter the data as per your requirement, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the parent of the `span` like the following way:

```js
document.querySelector('h1.page-title span').textContent = 'test string';
```

```html
<div id="content" class="clearfix">

  <header class="page-header">
    <h1 class="page-title">
      <span>
        Archives                    
      </span>
    </h1>
  </header><!-- .page-header -->

<div class="article-container">
```

**jQuery Solution:**

```js
$('h1.page-title span:first').text('test string');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" class="clearfix">

  <header class="page-header">
    <h1 class="page-title">
      <span>
        Archives                    
      </span>
    </h1>
  </header><!-- .page-header -->

<div class="article-container">
```

Comment: this exists in my php file. So I replaced it with this. <?php ?><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.page-title span:first').text('test string');
</script> It's still not working.

Comment: It is good, but you are assuming that he uses JQuery, while there aren't JQuery code on his try, it will be better if you give an non-JQuery solution also.

Comment: @D.Smania, I answered with jQuery becuase that was tagged in the question....I have added the JavaScript solution also.........thanks

Comment: @Mamun, I know was tagged JQuery, but he was not using it, so appears (at least to me) he needed a non-JQuery solution. Now looks better, +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the script is running before any HTML elements are loaded. Either place the `script` section at the bottom of your HTML, for example, just before your `</body>` tag, or make it into a function that is called after the document loads like so...

```
<script>
function replaceValue(){
    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for(var i=0;i<spans.length; i++) {
        if(spans[i].innerHTML.contains("Archives")) {       //is this the "Welcome" span?
        spans[i].innerHTML = "test string";  //change to new value
        break;                                  //hop out of the loop, we're done
        }
    }
}
</script>

....
...
<body onLoad="replaceValue();">....
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't just put it at the bottom of the html. Each Archive has its own tagname, so instead of the deatult "Archive" I want to give its tagname...(generated in the page title)